# Why is this assert failing?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assert

The `assert` in `main.cpp` is failing, and I don't understand why.
Here is `string.hpp`

```
class String
{
private:
    int len;
    char* str;
public:
    String(char const* s);      // C-string constructor
    ~String() {delete str;};    // destructor
    char* const getString();    //get string for printing
};

inline bool operator==(String lhs, String rhs)
{
    return std::strcmp(lhs.getString(),rhs.getString());
}

// Define operator!= in terms of ==
inline bool operator!=(String const& lhs, String const& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

and here is `string.cpp`

```
String::String(char const* s)   // C-string constructor
{
    len = std::strlen(s);
    str = new char[len+1];
    std::strcpy(str,s);

}

char* const String::getString()
{
    return str;
}
```

and here is `main.cpp`

```
#include <cassert>
int main()
{
    String c = "c";
    String d = "d";

    assert(c == c);
    assert(c != d);
}
```

I tried to include only the essential code. I left out a lot of the obvious includes. The `assert(c == d)` is failing and I don't understand why. The operator overload of == should have returned a true result.

Comment: There's no `assert(c == d)`…

Comment: You need to follow the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/241631). Your `operator==` takes the `String`s by value which will result in double deletion otherwise.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand: You memory management is horribly wrong. There is also no need to pass the arguments of comparison operators by value, use `const&` instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Please explain?

Comment: you need delete str[]

Comment: you do know that c++ has a string class already :-)

Comment: @LeonhartDan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three has an example almost identical to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 when its arguments have equal contents.

So add a comparison with 0 to your `operator==`:

```
inline bool operator==(String const& lhs, String const& rhs)
{
    return std::strcmp(lhs.getString(), rhs.getString()) == 0;
}
```

Also, since you probably don't want to copy the arguments each time you call `operator==`, I'd recommend passing them by reference.

Answer (score 1):

`std::strcmp` returns `0` if the strings are equal. So your `operator==` will return `false` for equal strings and `true` else.

You could, for instance, switch the implementations of `==` and `!=` around,